# Beginnings of Greek Mathematics

Tags: geometry, math-history

For another proof of the pythagorean theorem, consider right triangle ABC (with right angle at C) whose legs have length a and b and whose hypotenuse has length c.  On the extension of side BC pick a point D such that BAD is a right angle.

From the similarity of triangles ABC and DBA, show that AD = ac/b and DC = a^2/b.

Comment: If you draw this triangle out with the indicated instructions, I am having a hard time picking a point to where angle BAD is a right angle? It doesn't seem possible

Comment: Sure it is. Extend $BC$ in the other direction than the one you considered.

Comment: Hmm, I may be doing something wrong, but I'm getting AD = bc/a and DC = b^2/a.  You are making a the side opposite A and b the side opposite B, right?

Comment: no it is a opposite of B and b opposite of A.  there is a picture in the book I would post it but I am not sure how to do the formatting.

Comment: I am disappointed at the closure: had done a lot of typing!

Comment: well I am trying to resort to the rules of similar triangles and sides and trying to set up a proportion but the answer is hiding from me.

Comment: I tried setting ac/b and a^2/b + b as variables to make a proportion but it did not come out as planned

Comment: I was thinking to represent the two sides AD and DC as variables and solve that way using proportions but that doesnt work.

Comment: I had written out most of the proof when the question was closed. Saved what was written to a file.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Thanks for the notification. As you can see, I really had typed quite a lot, and only had the Remark part to finish.  The logic of *Elements* is really quite interesting, the theory of proportionality particularly so. To me, the Eudoxean theory, (in hindsight/reinterpretation!), comes shockingly close to developing a rigorous theory of real numbers.

Comment: @AndréNicolas You're right Euclid develops quite a lot of what we would call properties of real numbers.  Here you can see Euclid's propositions in Book V written in modern algebraic notation: aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookV/bookV.html#guide ; it's quite impressive, given that he had to say all that stuff in words.  Dedekind actually got his inspiration for his construction of real numbers as Dedekind cuts from Eudoxus' theory of proportions.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a picture as follows: $B$ and $C$ are on a horizontal line, with $B$ to the **left** of $C$. Point $A$ is directly **above** $C$.

Extend the line $BC$ to the **right**, and let $D$ be a point on the extended line such that $\angle BAD$ is a right angle.

By angle-chasing, we can show that the three triangles $ABC$, $BDA$, and $ACD $ are all similar.

By the similarity of $ABC$ and $BDA$, we have $\dfrac{b}{a}=\dfrac{AD}{c}$. It follows that $AD=\dfrac{bc}{a}$.

By the similarity of $ABC$ and $ACD$, we have $\dfrac{b}{a}=\dfrac{CD}{b}$, and therefore $CD=\dfrac{b^2}{a}$.

Note that the area of $\triangle ABD$ is the area of $\triangle ABC$ **plus** the area of $\triangle ACD$.

1. The area of $\triangle ABD$ is $\dfrac{1}{2} c(AD)$. This is $ \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{bc^2}{a}$.
2. The area of $\triangle ABC$ is $\dfrac{1}{2}ab$.
3. The area of $\triangle ACD$ is $\dfrac{1}{2}b(CD)$. This is $\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{b^3}{a}$.

It follows that 
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{bc^2}{a}=\frac{1}{2}ab+\frac{1}{2}\frac{b^3}{a}.\tag{1}$$

Multiply both sides of (1) by $\dfrac{2a}{b}$. We get
$$c^2=a^2+b^2.$$

**Remark:** The above proof can be found in Euclid's *Elements*, I think in Book VI, after the theory of proportions has been developed. It is an interesting supplement to the classical proof in Book I.

The language used by Euclid is different from the one in the proof above, since the algebraic manipulation that we used was not available. But the fundamental idea is the same. Indeed, one could argue that the proof in *Elements* is nicer.

I prefer the following argument. Drop a perpendicular from $C$ to $AB$, meeting $AB$ at $E$. Then the original $\triangle ABC$ is divided into two triangles similar to $\triangle ABC$, with hypotenuses $a$ and $B$. Now we can use a similarity argument. The "algebra" is a little more natural, the argument has greater symmetry.

But most importantly, in my view, the division of $\triangle ABC$ leads to a totally conceptual argument. Recall that the area of similar figures is proportional to the **squares** of their linear dimensions. So $\triangle BCE$ has area $ka^2$ for some $k$, the area of $\triangle ACE$ is $kb^2$, and the area of $\triangle  ABC$ is $kc^2$.

Thus $ka^2+kb^2=kc^2$, and the Pythagorean Theorem follows.

With some rewording, all hints of "algebra" can be removed, and we get the theorem in its original form: The square **on** $a$ plus the square **on** $b$ is equal to the square **on** $c$. The original Euclidean theorem did not say the square **of**, there was no multiplication involved.